# MYSQL problem: How to add values from one table to another

Tags: mysql, select

I have problem with probably a simple matter:
I want to insert data from one table into another.

TO THIS table :

```
(ID_autor, name, surname)
```

FROM THIS :

```
autor(ID_autor, name, surname, nationality, birthday)
```

This is my code :

```
INSERT INTO tab1 (ID_autor, name, forname)
SELECT ID_autor, name, forname, nationality, birthday
FROM autor;
```

But I dont know why it is bad ?????

Comment: The basic idea is right, but you're selecting 5 columns and inserting into only 3 columns. How do you expect that to work?

Comment: You're also inserting in the opposite direction than you want.

Comment: my mistake, I wrote it wrong, I corrected it

Comment: Just select the 3 columns you want to copy. Leave out `nationality` and `birthday`

Comment: but i want to insert values ​​from table autor into tab1

Comment: Where do you want those values to go? There's no `nationality` and `birthday` columns in `tab1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only select the columns that have corresponding columns in the destination table. Since there's no `nationality` or `birthday` columns in `tab1`, leave those out of the `select` list.

```
INSERT INTO tab1 (ID_autor, name, forname)
SELECT ID_autor, name, forname
FROM autor;
```